# ProjectEuler Q1 Program unexpected result

Tags: c#

I was working on problem one and my original program looked like this

```
int multiplesof=1000,count=0, multiple1 = 3, multiple2 = 5,val1,val2,sum=0;

while (count < multiplesof)
{
    if (count % multiple1 == 0)
        sum = sum += count;
    if (count % multiple2 == 0)
        sum = sum += count;
    count++;
}
Console.Out.WriteLine(sum + " is the sum of all multiples");
Console.In.ReadLine();
```

It give me the solution of 266333. This proved to be wrong, stumped I looked at Google. I have since gotten the correct value of 233168 with the following loop. However to me they look like they do exactly the same thing. Could anyone please explain why they are bring up different answers?

```
while (count < multiplesof)
{
    if (count % multiple1 == 0 || count % multiple2 == 0)
        sum = sum += count;
    count++;               
}
```

Comment: your below code is correct. try that...

Comment: There's also no need for `sum = sum += count;`. `+=` already means add and assign. Just use `sum += count;`

Comment: There's also no need for that much lines of code: `Enumerable.Range(1, 1000 - 1).Where(x => (x % 3) == 0 || (x % 5) == 0).Sum()`

Comment: @SargeBorsch There is also no need for linq, this has a closed form solution - i.e. no need for loops.

Comment: @NikoDrašković OK, but it requires a bit of thinking. :)

Comment: @SargeBorsch But isn't that what makes it beautiful? :)

Comment: @NikoDrašković Of course, yes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you added twice if it was a multiple of both 3 and 5, like when it was 15.

<sub>An alternative solution and also a spoiler if you were going to try to solve it yourself:</sub>

> `int result = 3 * (999 / 3 * (999 / 3 + 1) / 2) + 5 * (999 / 5 * (999 / 5 + 1) / 2) - 15 * (999 / 15 * (999 / 15 + 1) / 2);`

Answer (score 0):

Think about numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5, such as 15. Your first attempt counts them twice.